# NSAppleScript and unresponsive interface - Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, thread-safety, applescript

I want to run some lines of applescript code from within my application. The standard way is to use the NSAppleScript class. However, because that code might take a few minutes to complete, I have to use a separate thread or the interface will stop. The big problem is, as it says [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html), the NSAppleScript class can ONLY be run on the main thread.

So, if I run the code on a separate thread, my app crashes; If I run it on the main thread, it stops. Any ideas?

Also, I considered using NSTask and the osascript command, but I saw somewhere (can't find the link) that osascript doesn't support user input such as dialog boxes and stuff. I'm not sure if that's true, but if it is then osascript is not a solution.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but maybe try use `NSTask` with `osascript`?

Comment: A little more info about what you're trying to do with the applescript would be helpful.

Comment: @theAmateurProgrammer tried osascript -e 'display dialog "Hello"' just to be sure. Doesn't work, got this error: 0:43: execution error: No user interaction allowed. (-1713)

Comment: @rdelmar I'd love to, but I can't. It's the user that writes the code, so I have to provide support for anything and everything. It's not like I'm using applescript to do something that could be done with objective-c before compilling the program. It's the user who writes it when using the app, so I HAVE to be able run applescript code that can take any time to complete without making the interface unresponsive.

Comment: You can use osascript. The "No user interaction allowed" means you have to tell an application to display the dialog when using osascript because osascript doesn't allow it. So try this instead and you'll see osascript works fine... although that might not help you anyway because you're saying the user writes the code and of course the user won't know to do this... osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to display dialog \"Hello\""

Comment: @regulus6633 Right... that works perfectly and would be a great idea if I wrote the code. But as you said, it doesn't really help since it's the user that writes it. I'm thinking I could probably create a helper app/executable that I would launch passing as args the code, etc. That way it's the helper that gets stuck, not the main app. But that kinda sounds overly complicated for something like this, doesn't it? Or is it the way to go? Also, just a thought: how does AppleScript Editor run its code?

Comment: I can't think of a better solution than a "helper". The AppleScript Editor does become unresponsive so I assume it's a normal app that runs the code on the main thread.

Comment: Right then... thank you. That's what I'll do then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up writing a helper for this, launched via NSTask. Here is the code, in case anyone's interested:

For the launcher:

```
NSArray* args = [NSArray arrayWithObject: <<AS code here>>];

task = [NSTask new];
[task setLaunchPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"ASHelper" ofType: @""]];
[task setArguments: args];
[task launch];
```

And the helper:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString* source = [NSString stringWithCString: argv[1] length: strlen(argv[1])];
        NSAppleScript* as = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource: source];
        [as executeAndReturnError: nil];
    }
    return 0;
}
```